# How to save filtered image widget to a file in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am using flutter and dart to build my photo editing app but I have got a problem which is how could I save all of this effect widget like (BackdropFilter , Opacity, RotatedBox, ...etc) into a file so I can save it.

my structure looks like:

```
BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.mode(
     sigmaX: 5,
     sigmaY: 5,
   ),
  child: Image.file(
   file,
 ),
),
```

I have used the image library but I got a bug when using the adjustColor method.

please help me,

Thank,

Comment: You dont need to save widgets, you need to save parameters of this widgets and then recreate screen with saved parameters

Comment: thanks, but I've forgotten to mention that the app I building will be a part of a social network so I have a structure of the database that doesn't contain these params.

Comment: Hi, is ther any proposal ? Save parameters but how can this be applied with use of image widget for example to get new image file to gallery.